# Copy row if cell contains a specific text out of a sentence

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, for-loop

I'm still new to macros and I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me figure this out.

Column "A" in excel contains several row as below (one column and no space between rows):

```
Design: 0120
Model  -traditional
COLOR - red
Design:0150
copybook - quantity to be specified
Design: 0180
Still in progress
```

I need to find the cell that contains "Design" and than copy all of the information below this cell to the next sheet, then find the other cell that contains the word "Design" and copy all of the information below it to another sheet.

How can I do that in vba? The entire cell contains "Design:0150",which made it hard for me to search for the word "Design" as it's part of a sentence in the cell. And how can I automate the copy and paste of each "Design" set?

Comment: Help us to help you, **post your current code.**

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this line in your code:

```
If Left(cell.Value, 6) = "Design" Then
```

This can serve the purpose here. 
If it doesn't work let us know your full code so that we can help better.